# Azure Functions deployment from vsc asks me for the Storage account. Whatever I select, I get an error

Tags: deployment, azure-functions, vscode-extensions, azure-storage-account

I was deploying to cloud Azure Functions multiple times and it always required me to:

1. Click small cloud icon called "Deploy" and select "Deploy to Function app..."
2. Then in the popup I select which one is it
3. After submitting I'm asked for the confirmation and the function starts local build and then sending to Azure Functions.

For some reason now I'm getting a new step between 2 and 3 which is a question for "**Storage account**". I do not recognise any of those storage accounts and I have never created them.

[image: Popup with "Select storage account]

Selecting any one of them returns a very weird error with no details at all:

```
{"Code":"InternalServerError","Message":null,"Target":null,"Details":[{"Message":null},{"Code":"InternalServerError"},{"ErrorEntity":{"Code":"InternalServerError","Message":null}}],"Innererror":null}
```

That applies to existing Azure Function that I used before. When for tests I just created a new Azure Function (in Azur), everything is back as it was.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem was with the env variables of the Azur Function (found in the configuration tab).

`AzureWebJobsStorage`.
Previously it was all right to have this variable key uppercase (AZUREWEBJOBSSTORAGE), but they must have changed that and now a CamelCase (AzureWebJobsStorage) typing is required.